# Fatal Error in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am facing a Fatal error:

> Class 'Controller' not found in D:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\blog.php on line 3

I am typing write and i watched so many tutorials they are also typing beginning code like this i tried  a lot to find out but got no reason

Comment: Always consult the current User Guide first: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using CI 2.O? Did you by any chance write the following in your controller:

```
class Blog extends Controller { ... }
```

If you're using CI 2.0, you should use the following:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller { ... }
```

You might have been watching outdated tutorials for CI 1.7.

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Make sure to follow the userguide along with whatever tutorials you're following; there's some changes in 2.0 which you should be aware of. You can still follow these tutorials though, just keep your eyes open and compare with the userguide.

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? if you're using the latest (2.0.2), make sure you use CI_Controller when extending your controller.
Seeing you named the file blog.php, your controller should be looking like this

```
Class Blog extends CI_Controller {

 function index()
{
  // your code...
}

}
```